# Web Component (polymer-quill) integration with Elm

Tags: elm, quill

I am trying to incorporate a WYSIWYG into my elm app.  I have added the [polymer-quill web component](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/chuckh/polymer-quill) into my app.

#### index.html

```
<script src="/bower_components/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents.js"></script>
<script>
  window.Polymer = {
    dom: 'shady',
    lazyRegister: true
  };
</script>
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer-quill/polymer-quill.html">
```

### src/Templates.elm

```
div [ ] [
    [ node "polymer-quill" [] []
    ]
```

Yay, I see the WYSIWYG in my app.  It works and acts like a WYSIWYG.

Now I want it to talk to Elm.  If this were a text input, I would do something like this:

```
myInput =
    input
        [ class "form-control"
        , Html.Attributes.type_ "text"
        , placeholder "My Input"
        , value model.myInputValue
        , onInput SetMyInputValue
        ]
        []
```

This is a two-way binding with `model.myInputValue`.  However, `node "polymer-quill" [value model.myInputValue] []` doesn't seem to get me anywhere.

`node "polymer-quill" [ content "This is some content" ] []` does not work either.

How the devil does one do this?

Comment: Based on my quick glance at polymer-quill's documentation, it looks like you need to use the `content` attribute instead of the `value` attribute. There's a built in `Attribute.content` which might work, or you can make a custom `Attribute.attribute "content" "<editor's content>"`

Comment: No dice, `node "polymer-quill" [ content "This is some content" ] []` still shows nothing.  Edited above.

Comment: Ah, ok, there's a javascript api.  `content "{\"ops\":[{\"insert\":\"Hello World! - Store as Delta\"}, {\"insert\":\"More Content\"} ]}"` works, have to figure out a wrapper though.

Comment: You could also try Attribute.property

Comment: Is this not a candidate for using a port?

Comment: I'd like to avoid it if I can.

Answer (score 0):

Use the on event to send data back into Elm

```
recordTextContentOnTextChanged =
on "change" <|
    Json.Decode.map QuillSetProblemContent
        textChangeDecoder
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. For the first half of the binding (putting text from Elm into the editor), it seems like the problem was that the `content` field was expecting a Json object, even though in their documentation they say it can be just a string.

I found that if I set `store-as="html"`, it will expect the content to be html instead and will work fine.

```
Html.node "polymer-quill"
    [ Html.Attributes.attribute "store-as" "html"
    , Html.Attributes.attribute "content" "Hello world"
    ]
    []
```

I still haven't figured out listening for change events, but if @Jonathan's answer works I'll edit this

---

Also, the only line I added to my html was

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer-quill/polymer-quill.html">
```

I'm not sure if your other imports are doing something or if the are necessary